# Make extended Django UserCreationForm able to save extra information to database

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-1.10

I've been trying to extend the default `UserCreationForm` to include an email, first and last names. This appears to be quite a common topic on SO *however* the logic error I am getting I have still not found a solution to.

Here is my code:

**forms.py**

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True, label="First name:", max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True, label="Last name:", max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

**views.py**

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/reg_interests/')
    args = {}
    args['form'] = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'login/registration.html', args)
```

The views and form technically work in the sense that I don't see an error message, however upon `user.save()` the first and last names are not saved to the database (but the email is).

I know that each of `email`, `first_name` and `last_name` are fields that exist in the default Django User object so the field not being there is not the problem.

**How come the extended `email` will save to the database but the `first_name` and `last_name` will not?**

*Note:* I am using the newly released Django 1.10 so I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: what do ```self.cleaned_data['first_name']``` and ```self.cleaned_data['last_name']``` return in RegistationForm.save() after calling super()?

Comment: I think its supposed to grab the data from the corresponding form field in the first part of the class, just like the email

Comment: let me restate that... if you add ```print(self.cleaned_data['first_name'])``` and ```print(self.cleaned_data['last_name'])``` above the line ```if commit:``` what do they return on posting the form with data in both last_name and first_name fields?

Comment: I tried that too thinking a `print` statement would at least output a blank line in the console but it doesn't, which makes me think the code isn't being run even though `user.save()` is definitely being run, hence my confusion.

Comment: it may not be run if: 1. the form is not valid 2. request.method is not 'POST' 3. The form did not provide required fields for the User model 4. other possibilities...

Comment: I would recommend putting in a debugging statement ```import pdb; pdb.set_trace()``` at the top of register_user and stepping through the code using pdb.